# Can multiple `FILE` objects share the same file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, io

From APUE

> Each  standard I/O  stream  (i.e. each `FILE` object) has  an associated  ﬁle  descriptor.

In a program, can multiple `FILE` objects share the same file descriptor?

If yes, is it done by calling `fdopen()` multiple times with the same given file descriptor, each of which returns a pointer to a different `FILE` object?

If I `flcose()` on a pointer to a given `FILE` object, will the file descriptor of the `FILE` object still exists and connects to the file, if there is another `FILE` object sharing the same file descriptor?

Thanks.

Comment: You never use `FILE` but only `FILE*` which is just a pointer and can therefore be easily copied.  Given `FILE *f` you can make a second object pointing to the same descriptor using `FILE *g = f`, but you can call `fclose` only on one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you seem to be asking for is what you actually want...

Comment: Also see Stevens' discussion of `dup`, `dup2` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's a very bad idea, since `fclose` closes the associated fd, and therefore yyou can only `fclose` one of them without it resulting in `close` on a file descriptor that no longer belongs to the `FILE`, and may have been reassigned for other use. In principle this happens even at process termination, unless you use `_exit`/`_Exit` or abnormal termination.

A related question is whether you can use different file descriptors (each produced by `dup` for the same underlying *open file description* with more than one file. For that, the answer is also yes, and while it may be a bad idea, there are rules POSIX specifies that make it safe if you follow them:

[2.5.1 Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand your reason for "it is a very bad idea". (1) If two `FILE` objects share the same file descriptor, will `fclose()` on one `FILE` object not call `close()` on the file descriptor, because there is still another `FILE` object using the file descriptor? Will `fclose()` on the other `FILE` object  call `close()` on the file descriptor, because no more `FILE` object using the file descriptor?

Comment: (2) What do you mean by "may have been reassigned for other use"? (3) What do you mean by "this" in "this happens even at process termination, unless you use _exit/_Exit or abnormal termination"?

Comment: @tim: there is no record in the `FILE` object that another `FILE`  object shares the same fd. When you `fclose` one of the `FILE*`s, it will close the fd. The other `FILE*` is then unusable. When the other `FILE*` is closed, the fd will be closed again. If that `fd` has not yet been reallocated, that's probably OK, though wrong; if it has been reallocated, closing it will close a fd still in use by some other part of the program, which will then get a spurious error when it tries to use its fd. Unless you call `_[eE]xit`, all `FILE` objects will br `fclose()*`ed whe n your program exits.

Comment: So i agree. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: @rici: why does the implementation of the C standard library not keep track of the `FILE` objects sharing each file descriptor? Is this some flaw of implementation or design?

Comment: @tim: because the C philosophy is to  not waste cycles checking that you didn't do something you're told not to do. People who don't break the rules would like to use thise cycles to do something more useful. If you're looking for a programming language which doubles as a nanny, there are many alternatives :-)

Comment: @rici: No, it has nothing to do with "not wasting cycles". It's that the knowledge is at a completely different layer. File descriptors are integer handles, and there's no way, even in a language with garbage collection, that you could track whether there are still references to a given file descriptor. The open file description is a shared system resource that must inherently be mediated by the OS, and the file descriptor is a handle on that. The `FILE` is a completely library-level abstraction; there is no way the former could track the latter.

Comment: @r..: of course it could be tracked. The library could keep a table of all the fd's underlying a FILE object, and produce an error if fdopen attempted to use one of them. But that would be a waste of cycles IMHO. If you wanted to check for debugging purposes, you could do that yourself using fileno to get the fd.

Comment: @rici: It could have been designed that way, but it wasn't, and imposing that condition would be contrary to the specification which can't just be randomly changed.

Comment: @r..: i'm not advocating for a change. I was simply trying to explain why it was designed that way. Oddly, I can't find anything in Posix which prohibits creating a new `FILE*` with `fdopen(fileno(afile), "r")`, but the list of interfaces through which you can acquire a fildes fir use with `fdopen` conspicuously doesn't include `fileno`. Perhaps I'll submit a change request; it seems to me that the intent was that fd's could not be reused in that way, but who knows.